# How to access all users using Rosters in XMPP ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am half way doing chat using XMPP. I have registered and logged in to ejabberd server.

I can see in web interface that there are 10 registered users and 4 online users. But Roster delegates not getting any contacts.

I have tried this solution. I did not get any results.

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];

if (queryElement) {
NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
[ArrayUsers removeAllObjects];
for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

    NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
    [ArrayUsers addObject:jid];
}
}
return NO;
}
```

What may be the issue ? Do I have to configure the server settings for this to get contacts. It will be accessible to all by default? 
Or, do i have to make a query to get the user details and automatically synced to CoreData storage.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the shared roster module was not enabled in ejabberd configuration file. You can just enable `mod_shared_roster` in your ejabberd config modules section (the people who know how to do will understand. I personally dont know! So seeked help from others in the company).
Then, the shared Roster option will be available in the web interface of the admin side of ejabberd server.

Now configure the server to see all users to be seen for every body using the following link: 
[ejabbered configuration](https://www.ejabberd.im/shared-roster-all?q=shared-roster-all)

Now, if you have logged in and set for automatic sync of Roster (XMMP framework by RobbieHanson Eg), you will get all users in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Shared Roster and get all users from the Roster. Check [this](https://www.ejabberd.im/shared-roster-all)